# What happens with tight boundary conditions in the V-CYCLE while doing numerical Electrodynamics

Tags: electrostatics, computational-physics, simulations

My problem is very simple to understand. We are trying to solve the Laplace equation in a domain that has sufficient boundary conditions to converge to some solution.

Our example is this.
[image]
2 Electrodes (1 outer Annulus and 1 inner circular Electrode) are in the center of our domain. The outer electrode is set at a constant potential of 30V while the inner one at a constant potential of -30V. In that sense the physical domain they both occupy, represent Dirichlet B.C. The edges of the whole rectangular Domain were set to 0V constant but i thought the photo would look boring so i set them to have an oscillating potential. This does not affect the point of the question i just wanted a nice desktop background.

So the easiest way to handle this computationally is by doing the Finite Difference Method.
[image]
I went for the explicit Jacobi iteration because it is embarrassingly easy to multi-process correctly.
The problem is both Jacobi and GS converge relatively slowly. Successive over-relaxation on the GS method can make it converge ~10x faster but Wikipedia says the V_Cycle can do it many orders of magnitude faster so i wanted to give it a try.

As i understand the procedure:

1. You start with a given Mesh in the FDM scheme.
2. Chose a number of inner iterations and Cycles you will apply (example 4 coarsening each 50 inner iterations)
3. You apply X inner iterations with an iterative method to converge the potential (Jacobi, GS, SOR etc...)
4. You Coarsen the mesh by mapping it in a lower resolution.
5. You apply X inner iterations to the Coarsened mesh
6. Repeat steps 3-4 until you are satisfied with mesh resolution
7. Now apply a sequence of mesh smoothing and Inner iterations until you reach your original resolution again (inverse of 3-5)
8. Steps 2-6 are 1 V_cycle iteration. You repeat until satisfied with convergence criterion

To note here is that you can either work with a number of inner iterations or inner convergence criterion for each coarsening/smoothing inside the Cycle.

- Now my problem here is this. What happens with boundary conditions in the FDM? I can see this work as intended in FVM and FEM because they can work with simplex elements or elements of arbitrary shape. That means i can define for e.x Dirichlet boundaries on an edge (in 2D case) and simply reduce/coarsen the number of faces that touch that edge.

My method to handle the boundaries of arbitrary objects is the Mask method. Each array is given a secondary array of the same dimension made up of Integers that are either 0 or positive (1 is a choice). Paired with if statements they can do Boolean logic when you iterate over them.
This is how our Mask looks like. Electrodes are represented by a 0, anything else is 1
[image]

For example, if we have a discrete 50x50 mesh that has a circle of radius 5 in the center at some potential P, we create a Mask 50x50 array that has elements 0 in the Same indices where our Potential array has value P. The Mask needs to have elements 1 over the indices where we want the Laplace equation to be calculated. So essentially the mask for a Circular electrode would be a matrix that has 0's where the electrode is and 1's everywhere else. It's actual potential would be a Matrix that has 0's everywhere, and some value P where the circle is.

When we do the coarsening process, Let's pretend we have 2 objects at constant potential that are very close. The smallest mesh element is a square of side 'h'.
The separation of the objects is ~2*h

When we coarsen the mesh by a factor of 4 (i.e we have a 13x13 mesh from 50x50 rounded to nearest integer) the resolution becomes a big problem, because now the electrodes are not spatially separated anymore, and hence the small space between them is also considered a Dirichlet B.C if we use the "coarsen_mesh" method i provided in code.

Like here, we dropped our mesh from 4K (2160x3840) to (10x19)
[image]

As we can see there is no more separation between the Electrodes. And the Mask does not recognize the Annuls at all.
[image]

The only 0 elements here that represent Dirichlet B.C are the 5 black squares in the center. The outer ring will get iterated over and will lose its status as a constant potential during upscaling in the second part of the V_cycle with the smooth function.

This has 2 outcomes IF YOU MANAGE to coarsen the mask correctly. (which i have not been able to do with high fidelity)

1. The small spaces between electrodes are considered Dirichlet. They are not iterated over and given values Higher than expected during iterations with higher resolution
2. Details about the exact geometry of the Array get lost during coarsen/smoothen cycles, and it might deviated from the coarsened/smoothened Mask. This is if you manage to smooth the Mask correctly because my Coarsen/Smoothen code does not work for 2-valued integer arrays without messing up the logic.

The literature on google on the topic is very scarce and i have only managed to find pseudocode examples that i had already come up with myself.

If anyone has experience on the topic, i understand that the Mask has to be re-applied to every down-res , up-res in the Cycle and need to be changed. But how do you avoid problems like very tight spaces, or the Mask deviating completely from the Potential?

Would the most logical choice of action be to ONLY keep track of the Mask shape during the first Coarsening Cycle? Because like this we are guaranteed fidelity for both low-res and high-res cases. Since we started with a high res mask we do not need to perform upscaling on the low-res Mask.

Code is found here in Jupyter format: [Here](https://github.com/dcthecook/electrodynamics/blob/main/CYTHON_Jacobi_Multiprocessed.ipynb)

Comment: *we have a 13x13 mesh from 50x50 rounded to nearest integer* That sounds very backwards. You should be defining the *coarsest* region to have $n\times m$ and then higher resolution items increment upwards. So you should be starting with 13$\times$13 and increasing to 26$\times$26 then to 52$\times$52.

Comment: I would also argue that if you want resolution $\sim$2160$\times$3840, starting from 10$\times$19 is ridiculous (also not mathematically correct? Wouldn't it work out to 8$\times$15 or 16$\times$30 if you're going backwards?). You should probably start with a grid that is useful (i.e., the mask is reasonably-well described) and implement whatever levels above that are needed to get to your desired resolution.

Comment: @KyleKanos As i understand You start in your original resolution of 4K, you plan a certain number of coarsenings in advance. For example you will half indexes 4 times each. Each of these coarsenings will get its own set of inner iterations. Then you perform the operation backwards. I agree upscaling from 30p to 4K is ridiculous but that is why i save the masks in memory each coarsening step. So i don't have to upscale it. Only upscale the potential and re-apply b.c

Comment: Unless your $n\times m$ are both divisible by $2^k$ and you're only using $k$ coarser levels, you're going to have a problem of interpolation at some point along the way. If you instead define $n\times m$ and use $k$ levels of refinement, then your maximum grid is $2^kn\times2^km$ and can use simple averaging.

Comment: @KyleKanos I actually went with a more elegant solution to use an if not loop in the jacobi_iterator so that the Mask does not only prohibit iteration, but it can be used to reapply certain values to the Potential array. Too bad i am stuck with an artifact and idk where the mistake is. Check it out

https://github.com/dcthecook/electrodynamics/blob/main/CYTHON_Jacobi_Multiprocessed.ipynb

Answer (score 0):

Here to give an update on the answer.

You can achieve very high fidelity Mask resolutions apparently by simply doing some proper rounding.

My downscaling function 'coarsen_potential' in the Jupyter Notebook i linked is ok but it needs to be rounded to either 0 or 1 and then convert the mask array to int using np.asarray(). For comparison i created this mask in 1080p:
[image]

The mask coarsening achieved by the old method:
[image]

The mask achieved by using proper rounding:

np.asarray(np.rint(coarsen_potential(mask, 0.02)), dtype='int')
[image]

Even tho there is loss (one can easily see the Symmetry disparity in the inner electrode) It is still better than complete loss of information.

Here we downgraded a 2160*3840 array by a truncation factor of 0.02 so the coarsened array has dimensions of 21x38

One other little problems that remains is the correctness of the interpolation back to higher dimensions. Since we are not guaranteed to get the exact same mask after in a coarsen-interpolate cycle, the best choice is to save the mask arrays in memory and interpolate only the potential and not the mask.

Another function called 'add_dirichlet' was created for this purpose too. Since the mask is refreshed every inner iteration of the V_cycle, the function will re-apply the dirichlet boundaries in the proper mask indexes of the new mask.

This solution should very elegantly take care of Dirichlet conditions for the V_cycle.